# Count variable characters with negative value

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I have a variable (vLUF) in a batch file with a negative number, -5.0, and I need to get the number of characters it has. I'm using a command, posted on above link, but the variable "count" returns with no value.

[how to count characters in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103677/how-to-count-characters-in-a-text-file-using-batch-file)

Display input variable:

```
echo input variable %vLUF%
input variable -5.0
```

Comando:

```
for %i in (%vLUF%) do @set count=%~zi

echo %count%  
%count%
```

I changed the variable to 5.0, 50, abc,... but the counter doesn't return anything.

Comment: You are trying to count characters in a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Option 1.** Using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _cnt_vLUF=<nul & call set /p "_vLUF=Value LUF: "
for /f %%i in ('powershell -nop -c $env:_vLUF.Length')do set "_cnt_vLUF=%%~i"

endlocal | echo\vLUF=!_cnt_vLUF!
```

---

- **Option 2.** Using `cmd /Unicode`:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _cnt_xLUF=<nul & call set /p "_xLUF=Value LUFS: "
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%G in ('"cmd.exe /u /c echo=!_xLUF!|find/v """')do set /a "_cnt_xLUF+=1+0"

endlocal | echo\xLUF=!_cnt_xLUF!
```

---

- **Option 3.** Using `set Variable=SubStrings`:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _cnt_zLUF=<nul & call set /p "_zLUF=Value LUF: "
for /l %%L in (999 -1 0)do if not "!_zLUF:~%%L,1!"=="" if "!_cnt_zLUF!"=="" set /a "_cnt_zLUF=1+%%~L"

endlocal | echo\zLUF=!_cnt_zLUF!
```

---

- Result:

```bat
vLUF=[Length]
xLUF=[Length]
zLUF=[Length]
```

Comment: Option 1 & 2 work for me but option 3 gives me an empty variable https://i.imgur.com/s21ETVn.png

Comment: @iTwasnTme still not working https://i.imgur.com/sqmLQ3S.png

Comment: @RicardoBohner please take a [screenshot of the code with the result...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdAA7.png)

Comment: @Itwasntme: I'm on Windows 11: https://i.imgur.com/soRkRnm.png

Comment: @RicardoBohner Thank you! I will see up close
 when I have Windows 11, I have no idea why it doesn't work on it

Comment: @iTwasnTme I'm on Windows 11, option 3 only works for me when I remove the space between `set _cnt_zLUF=<nul` and `&`, or I use `/p`. It seems that cmd is moving that space before `<nul`, so without `/p` _cnt_zLUF will be one space.

Comment: @jingyu9575 thanks you! Good one!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how you can count the number of characters from a variable:

```
@echo off
:Start
cls
echo.
set /p "String=Please Inform a String: "
set Counter=0

:Loop
call set Temp=%%String:~%Counter%,1%%
IF Defined Temp (
                 set /a Counter+=1
                 goto :Loop
                ) 

echo  String: %String%
echo  Chars:  %Counter%
echo.
pause
goto :Start
```

Comment: funcionou também! obrigado.