# If statement with negative variables

Tags: windows-10, batch

My input variable contains only negative values, -5.0, -10.0... which will be checked by an IF statement. When the variable is less than -5.0, eg. -4.9, -3.0,... an invalid value message will be sent.

To avoid the comparison involving the negative sign, I count the characters of the variable to get the value of the variable without the sign, see below:

I used this link to use the character count in the variable:
[Count variable characters with negative value](https://superuser.com/questions/1716666/count-variable-characters-with-negative-value/1716695?noredirect=1#comment2648578_1716695)

First variable:

```
set /p _vLUF=LUFS value: -5.0
echo vLUF: %vLUF%
vLUF: -5.0
```

Second variable:

```
set /p _vLUF=LUFS value: -10.0
echo vLUF: %vLUF%
vLUF: -10.0
```

Counting the characters of the variable:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (v)do set _cnt_%%~i=<nul
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%G in ('"cmd.exe /u /c echo=!_vLUF!|find/v """')do set /a "_cnt_vLUF+=1+0"

First variable: has 4 characters
Second variable: has 5 characters
```

Removing the sign from the variable:

```
If !_cnt_vLUF!==4 (
 set positive=%_vLUF:~1.3%
)ELSE (
 set positive=%_vLUF:~1.4%
)

echo first variable: !positive!
first variable: 5.0

echo second variable: !positive!
second variable: 10.0
```

If statement to send warning message:

```
If "!positive!" lss "5.0" (
  SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
  echo %ESC%[31mInvalid LUFS Value! Valid values:%ESC%[32m
  -70.0 to -5.0%ESC%[0m%ESC%[31m.%ESC%[0m%ESC%
  [31mReturn? (y=yes/enter=exit^) %ESC%[0m
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  set /p r=""
  IF /i "!r!"=="s" goto SETLUFSPEAK
  goto notfound
)
endlocal
```

As long as the value of the variable is between 0.0 to 9.9, the If statement works correctly, eg:

```
3.0 invalid value message
4.9 Invalid value message
5.0 process without error message
9.9 process without error message
```

but when the value goes to 10.0, the IF statement considers the value 10.0 less than 5.0 and issues the error message when it should process the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions basically using substrings

```bat
@echo off 

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%i in ($E,$H)do for /f skip^=4 %%$ in ('
     echo;prompt;%%~i^|cmd')do set "_%%~i=%%$"

set /p "'=!_$E![0m" <nul & cd /d "%~dp0"

%:^[
set "_var=LUF,len,pos+,int,dig,var"
for %%i in (%_var%)do call set "_%%i="

set /p "_LUF=-!_$H!  !_$E![1;4;32mValor LUFs:!_$e!" <nul 
set /p "_LUF=[0m !_$E![4;1;33m" || goto %:^(
set /p "'=!_$e![0;0m" <nul & color

=;(echo;!_LUF!|findstr /b \0.*
   echo;!_LUF!|findstr /e \.[0-9]
   echo;!_LUF!|findstr /b \-[0-9].*
   echo;!_LUF!|findstr /vr "[a-Z] \+" 
  );= >nul && (set "_pos+=!_LUF:-=!") || goto %:^(

set /a "_cnt=0, _len=0"
set "_int=!_pos+:.%_pos+:*.=%=!"
set "_=%_pos+:*.=" && set "_dig=%"

for /f tokens^=1*^ delims^=. %%i in ('
     echo;!_pos+!')do if 1%%~i%%~j gtr 1700 =;(
         goto %:^();= else if 1%%~i%%~j leq 149 goto %:^(

for /f tokens^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%x in =;('
    "cmd.exe /u /c echo;!_LUF!|find/v """
    ')do set /a "_len+=1+0"

set "_len=0!_len!" && call set "_len=!_len:~-2!"
echo\!_$E![0m & echo\!_$H!!_$E![1F!_$E![0J
goto %:^]

%:^(
echo\!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E![0J && color

set /p "'=-!_$H!  !_$E![1;31mInvalid LUFs Value^! Valid values: " <nul 
set /p "'=!_$E![32m-70.0 to -5.0!_$E![1;31m!_$E![32m " <nul  
set /p "'=!_$E![1;33mTry Again?!_$E![7m!_$E![0m " <nul

call & choice 

if "%errorlevel%" == "1" =;(
    echo;!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E![1F!_$E![0J & goto %:^[
   );= else endlocal && goto :eof 

%:^]
:: your next command became here... 
echo;!_$E![1F!_$E![0J
set /p "'=-!_$H!  !_$E![1;04m!_$E![1;32mInput vLUF: !_$E![33m!_LUF!!_$E![1;32m ^| " <nul 
set /p "'=!_$E![1;32mPositive: !_$E![33m!_pos+! !_$E![1;32m^| Length: " <nul 
set /p "'=!_$E![33m!_len! !_$E![1;32m^| Value: " <nul 
set /p "'=!_$E![33m!_int!!_dig!!_$E![0m " <nul
 
echo\ & echo;  Obs: I'm in label %%^:^]
endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135726/discussion-on-answer-by-itwasntme-if-statement-with-negative-variables).

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:

```
set /p _vLUF=Valor LUFS:
set _cnt_vLUF=0
```

I inserted the character "0" at the beginning of the string where the counter is equal to 4:

```
If !_cnt_vLUF!==4 (
 set positivo=%_vLUF:~1,3%
 set positivo=0!positivo!   # inserted the character "0" at the beginning string
)ELSE (
 set positivo=%_vLUF:~1,4%
)
```

and changed the fixed comparison value from "5.0" to "05.0":

```
If "!positivo!" lss "05.0" (       # changed the fixed comparison value to "05.0" 
 SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
 echo %ESC%[31mInvalid LUFS Value! Valid values:%ESC%[32m
 -70.0 to -5.0%ESC%[0m%ESC%[31m.%ESC%[0m%ESC%
 [31mReturn? (y=yes/enter=exit^) %ESC%[0m
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
 set /p r=""
 IF /i "!r!"=="s" goto SETLUFSPEAK 
 goto notfound
)
endlocal
```

So the IF instruction can make the correct comparison between the values:

`If "01.0" lss "05.0";    If "04.9" lss "05.0";    If "10.0" lss "05.0"...`